# Sort a string array alphabetically ignoring numbers and symbols

Tags: c#, string, sorting

I'm trying to sort a string array that contains numbers just by the letters so for example:

`Original array = {"09Bananas", "Pears2", "Mangoes39Bad", "100Apples", "Mangoes38Good"}`

Should become:

`Sorted array = {"100Apples", "09Bananas", "Mangoes39Bad", "Mangoes38Good", "Pears2"}`

However when I try to use `Array.sort(original)` it would come out like this:

`{"09Bananas", "100Apples", "Mangoes38Good", "Mangoes39Bad", "Pears2"}`

Is there an overload of `Array.sort` that would make it ignore numbers?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Array.Sort<T>(T[],IComparer<T>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bzw8611x.aspx) overload, and skip digits before comparing strings.

```
var array = new[] {
    "09Bananas", "Pears2", "Mangoes39Bad", "100Apples", "Mangoes38Good"
};
Array.Sort(array, (a,b) => {
    a = new string(a.Where(char.IsLetter).ToArray());
    b = new string(b.Where(char.IsLetter).ToArray());
    return a.CompareTo(b);
});
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", array));
```

The LINQ expression `a.Where(char.IsLetter).ToArray()` converts a string to an array of individual letters.

Answer (score 3):

You could write a method that returns the string without digits and use that with [`Enumerable.OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx):

```
private string TextOnly(String input)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (Char c in input)
        if (!Char.IsDigit(c))
            sb.Append(c);

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

use it:

```
var original = new[] { "09Bananas", "Pears2", "Mangoes39Bad", "100Apples", "Mangoes38Good" };
var ordered = original.OrderBy(s => TextOnly(s));
// if you need it as: String[] orderedArray = ordered.ToArray();
```

To order the original array instead, you can use [`Array<T>.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxt053xf.aspx) as @dasblinkenlight has mentioned:

```
Array.Sort<String>(original, (s1, s2) => TextOnly(s1).CompareTo(TextOnly(s2)));
```